# How can I optimise this slow nested loop in R using the (L,S)apply family?

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

Here's an example:

```
result <- array(1, c(7,7,7))
for(i in 1:7){
  for(j in 1:7){
    for(k in 1:7){
      result[i,j,k] <- i*j*k
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: For this example you could use `outer(outer(1:7, 1:7), 1:7)` to obtain "result". What are your actual computations to fill in "result"?

Comment: You need to provide some data for people to work with.

Comment: The actual values are in another dataframe. I'd call this dataframe using i,j,k as indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `%o%` which is much faster than the loop. This is the same as using `outer`

```
> 1:7 %o% 1:7 %o% 1:7

> identical(result, 1:7 %o% 1:7 %o% 1:7)

library("microbenchmark")

> microbenchmark(1:7 %o% 1:7 %o% 1:7,    forloop = for(i in 1:7){
+    for(j in 1:7){
+     for(k in 1:7){
+       result[i,j,k] <- i*j*k
+     }
+   }  
+ } )
Unit: microseconds
                expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq      max neval
 1:7 %o% 1:7 %o% 1:7  19.673  21.3000  30.54441  26.030  30.4610  269.072   100
             forloop 680.274 693.1025 730.68298 703.042 716.6775 1367.285   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this

```
result <- array(apply(expand.grid(1:7,1:7,1:7),1,prod),c(7,7,7))
```